# Update NuGet Packages, DEP0700 error appears

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2022, winui

I've simply updated the NuGet packages(Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK,Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D, Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers, Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) using Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Manage NuGet packages for Solution. Suddenly the app is no longer working. This error appears :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80080204] error 0x80080204: App manifest validation error: Line 25, Column 6, Reason: The element specified requires "runFullTrust" capability.

In the past I've bumped into the same error(then there were some minor changes such as changing a color for a button or sth else) but I was just closing Visual Studio 2022 and deleting the .vs folder. Then starting again Visual Studio and press Debug button. Everything started working again. Now I've deleted .vs, bin and obj but to no avail. There is no full trust capability added so I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 0):

For you situation, I suggest you to go to the nuget package cache path, by default it will be:

`C:\Users\<Your User Name>\.nuget\packages`

At this place you will find the cache of the packages that installed before.

You can try to roll back to the previous versions.

You need to test the old versions because of the compatibility.

By the way, you can use git to avoid this situation next time, it will quickly roll back to the previous state.

Comment: I have used Git to revert to old commit. The issue is that I want to use packages with a greater version number. More specifically I want to migrate Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from 1.1.0 to 1.3.230502000 without 'runFullTrust' error to pop up.